# How to cut a circle from multi layered square artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, artboard

I have a square artboard in illustrator CS6. There are multiple layers and sub-layers on the board. I want to have a circular artboard and keep the editing capabilities within the circle if possible (not essential). I then want to place my circular artboard (design) on top of another illustrator artboard so that you only see the details within the circle. Can I do this or can I make the information that is outside the circle transparent?

Comment: Its called a clipping mask.... but everything has to be in one layer.

Comment: Terminology can be important. It is *impossible* to create an **artboard** that is anything other than rectangular. It just can not be done. You *can* create art**work** that is circular in nature however.

Comment: Thanks Joojaa. You are correct Scott. Forgive my ignorance of correct terminology! I need to cut a circular artwork out of my artboard. I want to place this circular artwork ontop of another document. Therefore, I believe joojaa is correct in that I simply create a clipping mask  but thereby forfeit editing capabilities? Thanks to you both!

Comment: You will only lose layers if you use a clipping mask. All clipping mask content has to be on the same layer. Is the layer structure important to you?

Comment: Thanks Scott. No the structure is not important...